# I've nested a ul in a ul but get an error. I've searched here but the solutions don't seem to apply

Tags: html

This is the error: Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Here is the html:

```
 <tr>     
 <td> Incorporated Business Accounts - additional requirements:

 <ul>

 <li> Business name and address  </li>
 <li> Nature of business and date of incorporation </li>
 <li> BIN number</li>
 <li> Certificate of Incorporation</li>
 <li> Names of company directors</li>
 <li> Names of directors </li>
 <li> Proof of signing authority </li>
        <ul>
        <li> Ltd Companies:  Memorandum and Articles of Incorporation/Bylaws </li>
        <li> Registered Societies:  Constitution and Bylaws or minutes</li>
        <li> Strata Corporations: Bylaws or minutes</li>
        </ul>
 <li> Photo ID for all signers: if more than 3 signers, must ID at least 3 of those persons</li>
 </ul>
 </td></tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ul should be inside li. Check the following

```
....
<li> Proof of signing authority
    <ul>
    <li> Ltd Companies:  Memorandum and Articles of Incorporation/Bylaws </li>
    <li> Registered Societies:  Constitution and Bylaws or minutes</li>
    <li> Strata Corporations: Bylaws or minutes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li> Photo ID for all signers: if more than 3 signers, must ID at least 3 of those persons</li>
 ....
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to nest in under a `<li>` tag like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
        <ul>
            <li>Nested item 1</li>
            <li>Nested item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```